# Using PHP to sort a SQL query from a dropdown table

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a table that is joined together using JOIN and I would like to create a form with a submit button that allows the end user to change how they would like the table filtered. 
The sort bar is on my webpage but it doesn't actually do anything. So my question is what do I need to do in order to get the sort button to work.

```
<?php


 $sort = @$_POST['order']; 
if (($sort)) { // If you Sort it with value of your select options
 $query = "SELECT n.firstname, n.middlename, n.lastname, m.title, f.format, t.price, e.series, t.inventory 
                FROM book_main AS m
                JOIN book_author AS n ON n.author_id=m.author_id
                JOIN book_title AS t ON t.title_id=m.title_id
                JOIN book_format AS f ON f.format_id=m.format_id 
                LEFT JOIN book_series AS e ON e.series_id=m.series_id 
                ORDER BY '".$sort."' ASC";



} 
else { // else if you do not pass any value from select option will return this
    $query  =  "SELECT n.firstname, n.middlename, n.lastname, m.title, f.format, t.price, e.series, t.inventory 
                FROM book_main AS m
                JOIN book_author AS n ON n.author_id=m.author_id
                JOIN book_title AS t ON t.title_id=m.title_id
                JOIN book_format AS f ON f.format_id=m.format_id 
                LEFT JOIN book_series AS e ON e.series_id=m.series_id
                  ORDER BY n.lastname ASC";


$results = mysql_query($query);
echo $results['order'];

//can I have a couple points for trying so hard haha...
}

?>

<form name="sort" action="" method="post">
<select name="order">
   <option value="choose">Make A Selection</option>
   <option value='lastname'>Authors Last name</option>
   <option value='price'>Price</option>
   <option value='inventory'>Inventory</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Sort" />
</form>
```

Comment: Ask a question please.

Comment: Agreed.  Are you asking us to make the submit button work?

Comment: Yes i am asking to have the submit button work. As it currently doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure the $sort has values listed in the select option you need a check as below. Also the reason nothing is echoing is, order is not a part of the $results array.

The only way to access the results is using any of these http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php

```
if(in_array($sort, ['lastname', 'price', 'inventory'])) {
    $query = "SELECT n.firstname, n.middlename, n.lastname, m.title, f.format, t.price, e.series, t.inventory 
                FROM book_main AS m
                JOIN book_author AS n ON n.author_id=m.author_id
                JOIN book_title AS t ON t.title_id=m.title_id
                JOIN book_format AS f ON f.format_id=m.format_id 
                LEFT JOIN book_series AS e ON e.series_id=m.series_id 
                ORDER BY $sort ASC";
} else {
    $query  =  "SELECT n.firstname, n.middlename, n.lastname, m.title, f.format, t.price, e.series, t.inventory 
                FROM book_main AS m
                JOIN book_author AS n ON n.author_id=m.author_id
                JOIN book_title AS t ON t.title_id=m.title_id
                JOIN book_format AS f ON f.format_id=m.format_id 
                LEFT JOIN book_series AS e ON e.series_id=m.series_id
                  ORDER BY n.lastname ASC";
}
$results = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['firstname'];
    echo $row['middlename'];
    echo $row['lastname'];
    echo $row['title'];
    echo $row['format'];
}
```

Comment: I tried using what you did here and It is still not sorting my table

Comment: Did you try running your queries on the database directly, is the order by working there?

Comment: Yes I can use an order by on the database directly as it is initially set to orderby lastname as the default

Comment: Removed the quotes around $sort, can you print the $query and check if it has the right $sort. Also it could be that lastname or any other select option is column in 2 tables and you might want to specify table  name as  "ORDER BY n.$sort ASC";